# Different grids for different sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to solve this with Bootstrap 3's grid system instead of using tables. I know how to create the two as two separate grids, but how would I be able to make the first grid and then the second xs grid appear at the appropriate screen width?

Thanks.

[image: grid problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution that which isn't bootstrap-centric but does the job: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/3XqDu/3/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: lightgreen;">

        <div class="col-sm-4 rows-on-same-line">
            <h3 class="well">CONTENT 1.1</h3>
        </div>            

        <div class="col-sm-4 rows-on-same-line">
            <h3 class="well">CONTENT 1.2</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3 class="well">CONTENT 1.3</h3>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and le finally a la css...

```
.rows-on-same-line {
    display: inline-block;
}
```